# Update column value with trigger postgresql/ fetch value from insert query

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update

Whenever user rates a movie such trigger should be called and update the rating of a rated movie.
How do I fetch value of movie_id from query `insert into ratings values (movie_id, /*etc*/)`?

```
create trigger new_rating after insert on ratings
execute procedure update_movie_rating();

create or replace function update_movie_rating()
returns trigger 
as $new_rating$
begin 
update movies 
set averagerating =
select avg(r.rating)
from ratings r
where r.movie_id = /*movieid fetched from insert query*/
return new;
end;
$new_rating$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-trigger.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming field in table "ratings"is called movie_id:

```
where r.movie_id = NEW.movie_id
```

You can find a detailed explanation here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

Anyway, you are interested in this specific part:

> When a PL/pgSQL function is called as a trigger, several special
> variables are created automatically in the top-level block. They are:
>
> NEW:
>
> Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for
> INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is null
> in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations.